# Supremum of $f_1(x)=1$ and $f_2(x)=x$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm trying to understand the supremem of a sequence of functions so I came up with a trivial case as follows -

Let $(f_n(x))$ be a sequence of functions with $n$ having a value of either $1$ or $2$. Ie. A sequence with only two elements.

Now if we define $f_1(x)=1$ and $f_2(x)=x$ what is the sup $(f(x))$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** The supremum is a function of $x$, which you can define piecewise. Consider what the supremum is in the two cases $x \ge 1$ and $x < 1$.

Comment: Ah yes now I see what is meant by the sup of a sequence of functions. Next up is to try and understand what the lim sup of a sequence of functions "looks like"!

Answer (score 1):

"Supremum" generalizes the idea of "maximum". So when you are considering the supremum of a finite collection, it is the same as the maximum. Specifically,

$$\sup \{f_1,f_2\} =\max\{f_1,f_2\}$$

which is meant to be interpreted pointwise. That is, for  a specific $x$,

$$(\sup \{f_1,f_2\})(x) = \sup \{f_1(x),f_2(x)\} = \max \{f_1(x),f_2(x)\}
$$

since there are only two values in the collection.